# check if ssl is enabled with php

Tags: php, ssl, detection

I need to run a module that need `ssl` to be enabled.
How can I detect if `ssl` has been enabled?

The module generate a form through a javascript call.

I am using php.

I have no  access to `ssl`.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: well you can check it using phpinfo(). There is part called openssl there.

Comment: hi, ssl, i did the correction on the question, thanks a lot. Unfotnutaly it seem  that php info is dsabled on this server thenks a lot

Answer (score 15):

use the extension loaded check!

http://php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php

```
 if(!extension_loaded('openssl'))
    {
        throw new Exception('This app needs the Open SSL PHP extension.');
    }
```

try it ;)

Comment: Hi, thanks  a lot, it seem  I have ssl enabled with this, but  if i see some javascript console, in firebug for example,  it still throw some warning about ssl not enabled. what can it be?  thanks a lot

Comment: You should post another question for this:) ..Also, make sure you select the answer if it answers your question!

Comment: This question is 4 years old, but this answer should have been marked as the accepted answer. Maybe @John will fix it ;)